# Audio does not start back after the interrpution

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I have two different problems.

My scenario is the following -> user plays an audio from Spotify, Youtube etc. and then starts the app and app will trigger the sounds automatically.

In iOS, Ducking works but after the duck the volume of the Spotify is not the same as before ( it has less volume)
In Android, interruption works but does not start the Spotify Back.
My Implementation:

service.js

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

module.exports = async function () {

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => TrackPlayer.play());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => TrackPlayer.pause());

};
```

App.js

```
await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({

            autoHandleInterruptions:true,
            iosCategoryOptions: [
                IOSCategoryOptions.DuckOthers
            ]
        });
        await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
            capabilities: [
                Capability.Play,
                Capability.Pause
            ],
            android: {
                alwaysPauseOnInterruption: true,
                // This is the default behavior
                appKilledPlaybackBehavior: AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.ContinuePlayback,
                stopForegroundGracePeriod: 2
            },
            icon: require("../assets/img/logo_app_rounded.png")
        });
```

Component

```
const playAudio= (audioId, lat,lng) =>{
    const url = BASE_URL + "/audios/" + audioId
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        let audioData =response.data
        TrackPlayer.add([{
            url: audioData.url,
            title: audioData.name,
            artist: "Artist"
        }]).then(() => {
            TrackPlayer.play().then(() =>{
                 console.log("Playing")
            })
            TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.PlaybackQueueEnded, () => {
                TrackPlayer.reset().then(()=> console.log("Track Player Reset"))
            })
        })
    })
}

await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({
            android: {
                appKilledPlaybackBehavior: AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.ContinuePlayback
            },
            autoHandleInterruptions:false,
            iosCategoryOptions: [
                IOSCategoryOptions.DuckOthers
            ]
        });
        await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
            capabilities: [
                Capability.Play,
                Capability.Pause
            ],

            // alwaysPauseOnInterruption: true,
            icon: require("../assets/img/logo_app.png")
        });
```